# Use django-registration or pinax account?

Tags: django, registration, account, pinax

I'm trying to build a very fast, lightweight django app. Would it be more appropriate to use Pinax (with their accounts app) or django-registration to handle my authentication? I know Pinax is solid, but there are so many dependencies, I'm not sure if I need all that added bloat/complexity. What do you think?

Comment: Does django-registration handle authentication? Or does it just handle registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use the django-registration myself. There is no reason to have that much dependencies, unless you need some modifications to some of their readily generate-able apps.

Comment: As questioned on the OP, does django-regitration handle authentication?

Comment: dotty, Yes. Infact the django comes itself out of the box with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I use django-registration with ease. Django's own registration is seasoned and can be modified to your needs.